# Reactjs Javascript if/else not working correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this if/else statement

```
import { isMobile } from 'react-device-detect'

const MoneyManagementOffers = ({ text, title }) => {
  const renderContent = () => {
  const checkDevice = isMobile ? <h1>Gela</h1> : <h1>Margo</h1>

  return checkDevice
}
```

Somehow it will always return `<h1>Gela</h1>` and I don't know why, Any suggestions, please?

Comment: there is not enough informationi here , your code seems ok...
when exactly do you expact to get different result?

Comment: when isMobile is true

Comment: it is dependency so it does his stuff by himself I don't have to write any code

Comment: I followed instructions but still did not work

Comment: if isMobile is true then `Gela` will be returned. You shouldn't ask that question here, you should go to Github and create an issue with the library. There's nothing wrong with your code, it's a matter of what happens under the hood in react-device-detect library.

Comment: console.log(isMobile) output?

Comment: There is no problem with the `react-device-detect`. I just copy paste your code and run on a sandbox. It is working as expected. I tried version `1.13.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { isMobile } from "react-device-detect";

const App = () => {
  const checkDevice = isMobile ? <h1>Gela</h1> : <h1>Margo</h1>;
  return <>{checkDevice}</>;
};

export default App;
```

This code works fine, maybe you need to switch to/from a mobile device view in your dev tools to see 'Gela' or 'Margo'.